# Triviality of a vector bundle is an open condition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Is the following statement true (and if not, are there additional assumptions that make it true?)

> A vector bundle on a variety which is trivial if restricted to a
>   closed subvariety is trivial on an open neighbourhood of this variety.

I would be particularly happy with a proof or reference treating vector bundles as locally free sheaves I am mainly interested in the cases of algebraic vector bundles over $\mathbb{C}$ and holomorphic vector bundles, although I think this statement would be interesting in other categories of vector bundles as well.

Some additional remarks and questions:

1) If the statement is true, can we weaken the assumptions? (e.g. more general classes of schemes instead of varieties, reflexive or even coherent sheaves instead of vector bundles)

2) There are two possible notions for "restriction" if thinking of a vector bundle as a locally free sheaf: Pullback to the closed subvariety in terms of sheaves or in terms of sheaves of modules. Does this distinction matter here or are the conditions (maybe by some Nakayama's Lemma argument?) equivalent in our case?

3) If *closed* would have to be changed to *proper/compact*, that would still be enough for me.

4) I think this holds in the continuous category by the following (sketchy) argument (Say $X$ is a paracompact Hausdorff space and the closed subspace is called $Z$):

On $Z$ there are $n$ linearly independent sections $s_i$.
Take a trivializing open cover of the ambient space $X$ for the vector bundle and extend the $s_i$ on each of the open sets having nonempty intersection with $Z$ (this is possible because wikipedia tells me that hausdorff paracompact spaces are normal). The extended sections are still linearly independent on (probably smaller) open subsets still covering $Z$ and we can glue them using a partition of unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch (and there are other methods too) for jorst.

For any point $p\in\mathbb{P}^2$, one has an exact sequence,
$0\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-2)\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-1)\oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-1)\to \mathfrak{m}_p\to 0$, where $\mathfrak{m}_p$ is the ideal sheaf defining $p$. Take a quadric $Q$ not passing through $p$ and consider the inclusion $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-2)\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}$ given by multiplication by $Q$. Then we can take the push out of the above sequence using this map to get an exact sequence, $0\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}\to E\to\mathcal{m}_p\to 0$. Using the fact that $Q$ does not pass through $p$, one easily checks that $E$ is a vector bundle. If we restrict to any line $L$ not passing through $p$, the sequence becomes,
$0\to \mathcal{O}_L\to E_{|L}\to \mathcal{O}_L\to 0$, which splits and so $E_{|L}$ is trivial. If these sections lift to $E$ in a neighbourhood of $L$, one sees that they actually lift to $E$ over the whole projective space. But then $E$ must have at least two sections, which is absurd from the exact sequence, since $H^0(\mathfrak{m}_p)=0$.

Comment: Hi and thanks for elaborating. I have two questions on this example: 1) It is not completely clear to me how to show that $E$ is a vector bundle.

Comment: and 2) Just to make sure there isn't an easier way: To check that a section in an open neighbourhood of $L$ is defined on the whole projective space I first show that the complement of its definition has codimension two (in fact otherwise Bézout's theorem would give an intersection with $L$) and then use that vector bundles are normal.

Comment: Your second comment is correct. For the first, to check $E$ is locally free, notice that outside $p$, by the exact sequence, since $\mathfrak{m}_p=\mathcal{O}$, it is a vector bundle. Near $p$, since $Q$ does not vanish at $p$, we are taking a push out with an isomorphism and thus $E$ is near $p$ isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}(-1)^2$, again a vector bundle.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y\subset X$ be closed and $E$ a vector bundle on $X$. If $E$ restricted to $Y$ is trivial and $H^0(X,E)\to H^0(Y,E_{|Y})$ is onto, then $E$ is trivial in a neighbourhood of $Y$. In particular this is true if $X$ is affine. On the other hand, in general, this is not true. For example, take $C$ to be an elliptic curve and let $V$ be the non-split extension $0\to\mathcal{O}_C\to V\to\mathcal{O}_C\to 0$. Then in $\mathbb{P}(V)$, one has a section $D$ with an exact sequence $0\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(V)}\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(V)}(D)\to\mathcal{O}_D\to 0$. So, the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(V)}(D)$ restricted to $D$ is trivial, but it is not trivial in any open neighbourhood of $D$.

Comment: Dear Mohan, does your section correspond to the trivial line  subbundle of $V$ ? And why is your line bundle not trivial in any neighbourhood of $D$ ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I find it quite hard to understand (I am not familiar with the theory of vector bundles on elliptic curves and do not know the terminology $\mathbb{P}(V)$ for example, I guess it is a projective space bundle?) It would be very kind if you could elaborate on your example and fill in some details.

Comment: @jorst, Why don't you just assume this? It is kind of difficult to explain in detail to someone without too many details.

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg, Yes, $D$ corresponds to the section coming from the trivial line subbundle of $V$. If $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ is trivial in a neghbourhood of $D$, one can see that $D$ moves and then $V$ will split.

Comment: hm, okay assuming a lot of things it seems to me that your argument works on every scheme that admits a non split extension as above. Is that a common thing to happen or something very special for elliptic curves? How about the case of $Z=\mathbb{P}^1\subset\mathbb{P}^2=X$?

Comment: Such cases also exist. There exists vector bundles on $\mathbb{P}^2$ which are trivial restricted to a line, but not trivial in a neighbourhood of the line. I did not write it here since it takes even more notation and justifications.

Comment: Could you maybe sketch that as well? In fact this is how I first encountered this problem: It is stated in this paper (http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.0215) on page 9 that this holds for lines in $\mathbb{P}^2$. I didn't see why, and the statement would have come in handy in another situation as well so I asked this question.

Comment: Just for clarification: Indeed the negative response to this question does not cause a problem with the abovementioned paper, as the author actually claimes a different thing: He states that a vector bundle trivial on one line is trivial restricted to lines nearby! I misinterpreted this.